# 'Next' what is it?

Tags: grammaticality

*Next* from English Grammar Today "is an adjective, an adverb or a pronoun" As a pronoun, it can be used with or without '*the*'. In Oxford Dictionaries it is called a ‘noun’ and use of the article is frequent.
Is the sentence '*Our bus stop is after the next*' correct with the article or without?

Comment: after the next one.

Comment: right- and in 'the next one' next is a determiner or adjective, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Next belongs to three word categories: adjective, adverb and preposition.

*The next train leaves at 13.45*.    [adjective as modifier of “train"]

*The play was next performed in 1901*.  [adverb as adjunct of serial order]

*Ed sat next to the mayor at dinner*. [preposition as head of PP]

In your example *Our bus stop is after the next*, the adjective "next" is a fused modifier-head interpreted as “next bus stop” (or "next one"), in which it is simultaneously head of the NP and modifier of "bus stop" (or of the noun "one").

Comment: I don't see a noun. Only an adjective, an adverb and a preposition.

Comment: **next** is a more or less a synonym for **nearest**. Is  **nearest** in  **Ed sat nearest to the mayor** also considered  a preposition in the contemporary analytical framework?

Comment: Yes: just like "next", "nearest to the mayor" has a locative meaning, so I'd take it as a PP

Answer (score 0):

Question about: Our bus stop is after the next' [grammatical?]

Correction: Our bus stop is after the **next one**.

**Next** is an adjective here. Just as colors would be: black, red, white or pink.

the next one = the is a determiner, next is an adjective, and one is a pronoun

Comment: thanks! can you give me an example of next or the next as a noun or pronoun?

Comment: @Inaeugenia The only instance of *next* as a noun that I could find would be in expressions such as, "Next, please, don't hold up the queue!" without the article.

Comment: @legionmamma978 thank you that's a good example ... from authentic English!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> The bigger fish usually eats the smaller.
>
> The fastest usually wins the race.
>
> The meek shall inherit the earth.

Superlative adjective **fastest** and comparative adjective **smaller** and the base  **meek**  are nominalized there.

The same thing can happen with **next** (which is actually a "collapsed" superlative meaning "nearest").

> The next to open his mouth gets detention.

It can be nearest is the locative sense or nearest in the sense of temporal sequence.